# cant connect to MYSQL server IP ADDRESS (111)

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I restarted my server and i have restarted following services

```
service tomcat start
service httpd start
service mysqld start
```

i still cannot connect to mysql server. i am facing this 111 error. Is there any other service to be started?

Thanks in advance

**Update**
mysqld and httpd status is running while when i check tomcat status it does not give anything.

Comment: Possible reasons: wrong port, wrong socket file path, blocking firewall rules or wrong ip.

Comment: ok. so how do we check these thing?

Comment: Well you only mention in your tags that you use _php_, but neither have post the part of your code where you try connect nor the exact error message. Infos like, Username and Password should for sure be left out, but the info if you use a `ip` and `port`  or a socket file, and how this looks like, has to be included in your question.